# How can an XML file be included into a mocha test case

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, mocha.js

I have written a test in mocha which is runned in karma. This test make use of some test xml data included in a separate file. The purpose of the test is to evaluate a parser. I have tried to include it using files in karma. But then I get an error "unexpected token <".

Comment: I had similar issue before. If I recall well karma will only load JS files so it's probably trying to process your file as something else generating the error message. I know it's not practical but could always use a string or a mock service which return the XML to be parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work, had left out "included: false" from 
`{pattern: 'test/mock/description.xml', watched: false, served: true}` which caused it to default to true. This lead to karma trying to including it in the html causing the error.